# Powershell - Get path location via Find-Path Function

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

So i wrote the code below

```
$datum_vandaag = $(Get-Date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$maand = $datum_vandaag.substring(5, 2)

if (-Not (Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\ITIL\**" -Include *$maand*)) { #(contains words gelijk aan (get-date)
    md -Path "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\ITIL\[??????]\$datum_vandaag"                        # Makes folder with name of current date in path:
    }
 
Else{Write-Output "test output"
}
```

The IF function is looking if in the path Desktop\ITIL** there is a folder that has the same number as the current date (07 is july) somewhere in the name of the folder.

Now i would like to make a new folder in the folder that is found by the command below :

```
Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\ITIL\**" -Include *$maand*
```

How could i get acces to this path so i can use it in the md command (now marked with [??????] in the code) Because currently i only receive if a folder is found, false or true.
All i could find what possibly would work is get-path or resolve-path but I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to fully understand what you are asking, but I think the command you are looking for is [Get-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) which will return an object to the named folder.

Something like this might work:

```
$path = Get-Item -Path "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\ITIL\**" -Include *$maand*
if ($path) {
  $newPath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $datum_vandaag
  New-Item -Path $newPath -ItemType Directory
}
```